# Прекращена работа программы vshost.exe

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

После почти каждого завершения откладки вылезает сообщение "Прекращена работа программы vshost.exe". Иногда сразу при запуске откладки, и, соответственно, откладка тут же завершается.
Использую vs 2015 community, пишу на c#. Как бы избавиться от этого?

Comment: попробуйте переустановить. и поставить update.

Comment: использую туже самую версию студии, никаких сообщений после окончания отладки не встречал

Comment: Дело в том, что я установил vs2015 буквально неделю назад, с iso-файла, так как у меня на компьютере, на котором vs, нет интернета.

Comment: @Theonic 15-я студия еще достаточно сырая. Пользуйтесь лучше 13-й, если в 15-й нету крайней необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

> Как бы избавиться от этого?

Не работает один из компонентов. Обычно помогает переустановка Visual Studio.
А чтобы понять в чем проблема, надо посмотреть сообщения об ошибках, которые выводятся в лог ([/Log (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx))

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml
```